# Multiple radio buttons getting selected in Rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have an app where `Question` model `has_many` relationship with `Option`. I also have a button to add options while creating a question. Every question has only one correct answer. So when I create a question and click on `Add Option` button, new option is created but the new `radio button` associated with it has different `name`. In fact the name of `radio button` is of the form `question[options_attributes][i][is_answer]` where `i` is `id`. As far as I know `radio buttons` should have the `same name` to work as a collection or group. So how can I make it work as a group even if I create any number of options for a single question?

**html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @question do |form| %> 

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.each do |a| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= a.label :options %>
      <%= a.text_area :body %>
      <%= a.radio_button :is_answer, "options" %>
      <%= a.check_box :_destroy %>
      <%= a.label :_destroy, 'delete' %>
    </div>    
  <% end %> 
 <%= form.submit 'Add option', :name => "add_option" %>
 <%= form.submit 'Delete options', :name => "remove_option" %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>    
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**controller.rb**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.options.build
  end
def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    @question.user = current_user
    if params[:add_option]
      @question.options.build
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        if @question.save
          format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Question was successfully created.' and return }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @question }          
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @question.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
    render :action => 'new'
  end
private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:body, options_attributes: [:id, :body, :question_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :is_answer])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Using JavaScript on the client-side to uncheck the radio buttons.
2. Using radio buttons with the same name. It this case you will have to change the way you pass the `:is_answer` parameter and manually assign the value in `options_attributes`.

**Method 1 details:**

See this question [radio different names - only check one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839995/radio-different-names-only-check-one)

**Method 2 details:**

Instead of passing `:is_answer` parameter for each option you can pass a single parameter for the question having chosen answer id as the value. Lets name it `"answer_id"`. We want this parameter to be in the `params[question]` 
hash in the controller, so the whole name will be `"question[answer_id]"`. Although radio buttons are generated for each option, only the chosen one will be sent to the server as they all have the same name.

```
    <%= form.fields_for :options, question.options.each do |a| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= a.label :options %>
        <%= a.text_area :body %>
        <%= radio_button_tag "question[answer_id]", a.object.id, a.object.is_answer? %>
        <%= a.check_box :_destroy %>
        <%= a.label :_destroy, 'delete' %>
      </div>    
    <% end %>
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/radio_button_tag

In the controller you will have to manually assign the option's `is_answer` parameter based on the `answer_id` value.

```
def question_params
  result = params.require(:question).permit(:body, :answer_id, options_attributes: [:id, :body, :question_id])

  answer_id = result.delete(:answer_id)

  result[:options_attributes].values.each do |option_attrs|
    option_attrs[:is_answer] = option_attrs[:question_id] == answer_id
  end

  result
end
```

If you need further details please let me know. I will update the answer to give more information.

Comment: Added more details

Comment: I tried the second method. I am getting `undefined method `options_attributes' for #<ActionController` error at this line `result.options_attributes.each do |option_attrs|`. So I changed it to `result[:options_attributes].each do |option_attrs|`. Now I am getting this error: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` at this line: `option_attrs[:is_answer] = option_attrs[:question_id] == answer_id`.

Comment: The `question` object is like this: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "question"=>{"body"=>"Which is the capital of Russia?", "options_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"body"=>"Moscow", "_destroy"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"body"=>"St Petersburg", "_destroy"=>"0"}}, "answer_id"=>"on"}, "commit"=>"Create Question"}`

Comment: Changed `result[:options_attributes]` into `result[:options_attributes].values`

Comment: One another problem: The selected radio button is not changing the value of `is_answer` to `true`. I have given the default as `false`. So even if I select a radio button, the value in the database is still `false`.

Comment: You have to debug your code in the controller and figure out what goes wrong. I gave you the idea, I cannot debug your code.

Comment: Ok. I will do it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193038/discussion-between-chumakoff-and-laxman).